# Dynamic Image Making

Tags: java, image

I want to make around 1000 images all are with just a few differences, I have a fixed size background color and logo placed. The difference is that on each one i want numbers from 1 to 1000 on one side and on the other side I have its representation on abacus, which can me made by hiding/showing 15 layers (Each containing 1 circle). So I am searching for a way to achieve this either by making a java program makes and saves all of those in 1000 `.png` files. Or maybe some other language than java. Note i just want someone to tell me how to put the numbers i will do the second part myself as you may not understand that. Mainly question is that I want 1000 png image files made automatically each with numbers 1 to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, where x and y are the coordinates where you want to paint the numbers:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 1001; i++)
    {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("pathtoyourimage"));
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.drawString(i, x, y);
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("outputpath/image" + i));
    }
```

Comment: I did not get your point that the coordinates x and y are where you want to print the numbers.... I will print them in jLabel right?

Comment: The x and y are the coordinates on the image where the numbers will be painted. So for example, 0 and 0 will print them to the very upperleft corner. And if you want the numbers to be in the lowerleft corner, use x = 0, and y = image height - ~20.